# method inline still slower than manually refactor (merge) into same method?

Tags: c#, inline

I used to think if a method is inlined, then theoretically it is identical to the merge of the method and the calling method, but the benchmark showed there is slightly difference in performance

e.g.  this takes 100ms

```
    public long TestA()
    {
        long ret = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < testSize; n++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    ret += myArray[i][j];
                }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

this takes 110ms  (if I force `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` on `GetIt` then it will be 400ms, so I assume it is auto inlined)

```
    public long TestB()
    {
        long ret = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < testSize; n++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    ret += GetIt(i, j);
                }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    int GetIt(int x, int y)
    {
        return myArray[x][y];
    }
```

OK, I attach a snippet of benchmark function i used

```
    public static void RunTests(Func<long> myTest)
    {
        const int numTrials = 100;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        double[] sample = new double[numTrials];

        Console.WriteLine("Checksum is {0:N0}", myTest());

        sw.Start();
        myTest();
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Estimated time per test is {0:N0} ticks\n", sw.ElapsedTicks);
        if (sw.ElapsedTicks < 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ticks per test is less than 100 ticks. Suggest increase testSize.");
            return;
        }

        if (sw.ElapsedTicks > 10000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ticks per test is more than 10,000 ticks. Suggest decrease testSize.");
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numTrials / 3; i++)
        {
            myTest();
        }

        string testName = myTest.Method.Name;
        Console.WriteLine("----> Starting benchmark {0}\n", myTest.Method.Name);
        for (int i = 0; i < numTrials; i++)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            sw.Restart();
            myTest();
            sw.Stop();
            sample[i] = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        }
        double testResult = DataSetAnalysis.Report(sample);
        DataSetAnalysis.ConsistencyAnalyze(sample, 0.1);
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < numTrials; j = j + 5)
            Console.WriteLine("{0,8:N0} {1,8:N0} {2,8:N0} {3,8:N0} {4,8:N0}", sample[j], sample[j + 1], sample[j + 2], sample[j + 3], sample[j + 4]);
        Console.WriteLine("\n----> End of benchmark");
    }
```

Comment: Please show how you were benchmarking.

Comment: Perf differences of 10% are not statistically meaningful on artificial benchmarks like this.  A mis-aligned branch target is enough to explain the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# does **inline** at **JIT**, so whether **inline** or not **IL** doesn't change.

`MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` is not the same as `inline` keyword in F#

Answer (score 1):

The resulting number of IL instructions differs slightly, the maxstack differs significantly:

```
TestA:
// Code size       78 (0x4e)
.maxstack  2


TestB:
// Code size       88 (0x58)
.maxstack  4

GetIt:
// Code size       7 (0x7)
.maxstack  1
```